# Optimization for Exponential Bacteria Growth Rate

Tags: calculus

I have attempted this optimization (through differentiation) question from the exercises I've received through a self-improvement course. I got stuck while differentiating the equation which is supposed to be the exponential growth model for bacteria growth, so I'm unable to solve for the answer, I am hoping someone can help to guide me through this question as I was and still am not adept at maths.

Here is the question: 
The bacteria population in a certain colony is given by

$f(t) = 1000t^2e^{-t}$

where $t$ is time in minutes and $t \ge 0$

Find the time at which the population reaches a maximum.

I've immediately attempted the product rule to try and differentiate, but as I said I got stuck, and I can't solve for $t$ without differentiating (I can equate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to 0 and then find the maximum). I'm also not sure where the information '$t$ is time in minutes' and $t \ge 0$ comes into play when solving.

Please let me know of the steps needed to complete the question and where I've gone wrong, I would love to learn, thanks!

I have attached two screenshots of the full problem, and my attempt at another screenshot.

[Problem Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwBYA.jpg)

[My attempted solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vsTY.jpg)

Comment: Your picture of your work does not have any explanation attached.  I couldn't easily see what you have done or where you are stuck.  One advantage of writing it up in MathJax is it forces you to organize your thoughts.

Comment: Noted, I'll keep that in mind and be sure to write up any solutions in MathJax in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really follow your handwriting or solution. It says how to solve the problem in the question with a derivative test.

$$ f(t)  = 1000t^{2} e^{-t} \tag{1} $$

the product rule is given as

$$ (g \cdot h)^{'} = g^{'} \cdot h+ g \cdot h^{'} \tag{2}$$

the constant doesn't matter here, it simply scales so instead look at

$$ f_{1}(t) = g \cdot h =  t^{2} e^{-t} \tag{3}$$

then we have

$$ g(t) = t^{2} , h(t) = e^{-t} \implies g^{'}(t) = 2 t , h^{'}(t) = -e^{-t} \tag{4}$$

which gives us

$$ f_{1}^{'}(t) = 2 t \cdot e^{-t} - t^{2}e^{-t} \tag{5} $$

we rewrite this as

$$ f_{t}^{'}(t) = e^{-t}t(2   - t)  \tag{6}$$

Then we have

$$ t = 0, 2 $$
$$ f_{1}(2) = (2)^{t} e^{-2}  = 4 \cdot e^{-2} = \frac{4}{e^{2}}  \tag{7} $$

so our maximum for $f(t)$ is given by

$$ f(2)  = \frac{4000}{e^{2}} \tag{8} $$